# std::thread - naming your thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

The new C++ has this std::thread type. Works like a charm.
Now I would like to give each thread a name for more easy debugging (like java allows you to).
With pthreads I would do:

```
pthread_setname_np(pthread_self(), "thread_name");
```

but how can I do this with c++0x?
I know it uses pthreads underneath on Linux systems, but I would like to make my application portable. Is it possible at all?

Comment: On Windows, the thread name is a debugger property (i.e. tracked outside the application itself). As a result, you don't have the equivalent of `pthread_getname_np`

Comment: Since Windows 10, 1607, there's [SetThreadDescription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-setthreaddescription).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A portable way to do this is to maintain a map of names, keyed by the thread's ID, obtained from `thread::get_id()`. Alternatively, as suggested in the comments, you could use a `thread_local` variable, if you only need to access the name from within the thread.

If you didn't need portability, then you could get the underlying `pthread_t` from `thread::native_handle()` and do whatever platform-specific shenanigans you like with that. Be aware that the `_np` on the thread naming functions means "not posix", so they aren't guaranteed to be available on all pthreads implementations.

Comment: "a map of names, keyed by the thread's ID" - or thread-local storage? Assuming that the debugging you're doing is only ever from inside the thread whose name you want to know, of course.

Comment: In terms of a design to wrap this idea up, you might want to consider using a ThreadFactory in your application, whose goal is to register threads upon creation and/or abstract away all of the `#ifdef`s required if you wanted to use the pre-compiler to select platform specific code.

Comment: The whole point of naming threads is to make debugging easier, because the debugger would show the thread's name, so maintaining some names map internally is kind of pointless...

Comment: @VáclavSlavík: Indeed, if you interpret "more easy debugging" as "displaying the thread name in a debugger", then the portable method won't help. It might be useful for other methods of debugging and thread management, though.

Comment: ⁺¹ for elaboration about `_np` postfix.

Answer (score 34):

An attempt at making a wrapper to deal with many Linuxes as well as Windows. Please edit as needed.

```cpp
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
const DWORD MS_VC_EXCEPTION=0x406D1388;

#pragma pack(push,8)
typedef struct tagTHREADNAME_INFO
{
   DWORD dwType; // Must be 0x1000.
   LPCSTR szName; // Pointer to name (in user addr space).
   DWORD dwThreadID; // Thread ID (-1=caller thread).
   DWORD dwFlags; // Reserved for future use, must be zero.
} THREADNAME_INFO;
#pragma pack(pop)


void SetThreadName(uint32_t dwThreadID, const char* threadName)
{

  // DWORD dwThreadID = ::GetThreadId( static_cast<HANDLE>( t.native_handle() ) );

   THREADNAME_INFO info;
   info.dwType = 0x1000;
   info.szName = threadName;
   info.dwThreadID = dwThreadID;
   info.dwFlags = 0;

   __try
   {
      RaiseException( MS_VC_EXCEPTION, 0, sizeof(info)/sizeof(ULONG_PTR), (ULONG_PTR*)&info );
   }
   __except(EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER)
   {
   }
}
void SetThreadName( const char* threadName)
{
    SetThreadName(GetCurrentThreadId(),threadName);
}

void SetThreadName( std::thread* thread, const char* threadName)
{
    DWORD threadId = ::GetThreadId( static_cast<HANDLE>( thread->native_handle() ) );
    SetThreadName(threadId,threadName);
}

#elif defined(__linux__)
#include <sys/prctl.h>
void SetThreadName( const char* threadName)
{
  prctl(PR_SET_NAME,threadName,0,0,0);
}

#else
void SetThreadName(std::thread* thread, const char* threadName)
{
   auto handle = thread->native_handle();
   pthread_setname_np(handle,threadName);
}
#endif
```

Comment: just to clarify the Windows part of this is from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcb2z8hs.aspx

Comment: On Windows, you may also want to use the SetThreadDescription() API: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41446477/434413. This is the new official API, which is being used in newer MS tools (the method shown in this answer is the old way of doing it, which only works for processes that are running inside the Visual Studio debugger at the time the exception is thrown).

Comment: Note: Windows code with RaiseException is catched in real time with debugger. I.e. if you RaiseException once at thread start and attach debugger later, it will not know thread name.

Comment: The Apple pthread implementation of `setname` does not take a handle - its just `pthread_setname_np(const char*)`: https://opensource.apple.com/source/libpthread/libpthread-218.1.3/src/pthread.c.auto.html  You should add an `#if defined(__APPLE__)` to handle that.

Comment: This will only work in the Visual Studio debugger unfortunately.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `std::thread::native_handle` to get the underlaying implementation defined thread. There is no standard function for that natively.

You can find an example [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/native_handle).

Answer (score 6):

For windows [debugger], you can easily use the "normal" method;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/xcb2z8hs.aspx

Just need the thread id which you can obtain via

```
#include <windows.h>
DWORD ThreadId = ::GetThreadId( static_cast<HANDLE>( mThread.native_handle() ) );
```

Comment: That will probably work but it is not a generic C++ and thus cross platform solution. Thanks for suggesting it anyway.

Comment: Oh it's definitely windows only, but nobody had actually told you how to set it on windows. (And it works, I use it :)

Answer (score 3):

I've both seen this done in a system predating c++11 (where we basically invented our own Thread class that was very similar to std::thread) and in one I wrote fairly recently.

Basically, the pool really puts std::thread 2 layers down- you have a PoolThread class that contains a std::thread plus metadata like its name, ID, etc. and the the control structure that links it to its controlling pool, and the ThreadPool itself. You want to use thread pools in most threaded code for several reasons:
1) You can hide all the explicit "detach", "join", start thread on std::thread construction, etc. from users. That produces MUCH safer & cleaner code. 
2) Better resource management: Too many threads will cripple performance even more than having too few. A well-built pool can do advanced things like automatic load balancing and cleaning-up hung or deadlocked threads. 
3) Thread reuse: std::thread by itself is easiest to use by running every parallel task on its own thread. But thread creation & destruction are expensive, and can easily swamp the speed boost from parallel processing if you're not careful. So, it usually makes more sense to have pool threads that pull work tasks from a queue and only exit after receiving some signal. 
4) Error handling: std::thread is just an execution context. If the task you're running on it throws an un-handled exception or std::thread ITSELF fails, the process will just crash right there. To do fault-tolerant multithreading, you need a Pool or something similar that can quickly catch such things and at least emit meaningful error messages before the process dies.

Comment: Concerning your point 2: If you add logic to your program to cleanup hung or deadlocked threads, you are merely trying to hide bugs. I would recommend fixing the bug instead. Something similar goes for point 4: If you get an unhandled exception to the top level of the thread, you have a fatal bug in your code. Again, the priority should be to fix the bug and not to "gracefully" handle the situation.

Answer (score 0):

In header file do:

```
const std::string & ThreadName(const std::string name="");
```

In src file do:

```
const std::string & ThreadName(const std::string name)
{
    static std::atomic_int threadCount{0};
    const thread_local std::string _name = name + std::to_string(threadCount.fetch_add(1));
    return _name; 
}
```

Usage:

```
void myThread()
{
   ThreadName("myThread"); // Call once at very beginning of your thread creation
   ...
   std::cout << ThreadName() << std::endl; // Anyplace in your code
}
```