# How to obtain thread name in android ndk

Tags: android, android-ndk, pthreads

In my Android project, I'm using `std::thread`.
I use the same C++ code also in some Linux and OSX projects.

For debugging purpose, I want to assign human-readable thread names and I do that by calling `pthread_setname_np()` (because lack of `std::thread::set_name()`).

In case of later debug output, I try to obtain the current thread name by calling `pthread_getname_np()` and this works e.g. on Linux target.

But for my surprise, there is no `pthread_getname_np()` in Android Ndk `pthread.h`, not in e.g. `ndk-bundle/platforms/android-19/arch-arm/usr/include/pthread.h` nor in `ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-arm/usr/include/pthread.h`

A stupid trying with a forward declaration like:

```
extern "C" int pthread_getname_np(pthread_t, char*, size_t);
```

fails with a linker error (as expected).

Any idea how to obtain the human readable name of the current thread in Android from C/C++ code?

Comment: This seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10121671/1524450

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can see how Dalvik sets them in [dalvik/vm/Thread.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/kitkat-release/vm/Thread.cpp#1198).  It uses `pthread_setname_np()` if available, `prctl(PR_SET_NAME)` if not.  So if `pthread_getname_np()` isn't available -- and bear in mind that "np" means "non-portable" -- you can use `prctl(PR_GET_NAME)` to get a 16-byte null-terminated string under Linux.

You can find other bits by fishing around in `/proc` entries.

If you have specific requirements for the size and format of the name then you may want to define a pthread key and tuck it into thread-local storage.  It's more work, but it's consistent and portable.